# RecyclerView Smooth Scroll animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, objectanimator

I had implemented a smooth scroll animation for ViewPager using OnjectAnimator. Now, i am trying to do the same for a recyclerView but the scroll animation is abrupt. Here is my animation using ObjectAnimator for a viewpager. It produces a snap animation to demonstrate the scroll capability of the viewpager.

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator
    .ofFloat(new PagerHintMovement(-10, viewPager), "progress", -1f, 1f);

objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
objectAnimator.setDuration(1500);
objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(1);
objectAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Animation: Starting fake drag on view pager.");
    viewPager.beginFakeDrag();
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Animation: Ending fake drag on view pager.");
    viewPager.endFakeDrag();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
      if (animation.getInterpolator() instanceof AccelerateInterpolator) {
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
      } else {
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
      }
    }
  }
});
objectAnimator.setStartDelay(1000);
objectAnimator.start();
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the same for a recyclerView ?

Comment: Is it `OnjectAnimator` or `ObjectAnimator` as stated in the question's third line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not satisfied with default [`RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#smoothscrolltoposition) you will need to do some class overrides.

Smooth scroll in `RecyclerView` is triggered by calling
[`LayoutManager.startSmoothScroll(RecyclerView.SmoothScroller)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#startsmoothscroll) on its current `layoutManager`.

You are free to override `LayoutManager` and provide custom [`RecyclerView.SmoothScroller`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.SmoothScroller) implementation - preferably by extending [`RecyclerView.LinearSmoothScroller`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSmoothScroller.html).

Comment: Thanks @Pawel. I basically want something like scrollBy (x, y). I tried translationX using ObjectAnimator but it's very abrupt.

Comment: Can you show how to override LayoutManager with custom smooth scroller implementation?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you need smooth scroll you may follow the following steps:

1. Hide the recycler view and display a progress bar there
2. Create a background asynchronous task where you setup and load the recycler view
3. While setting data in the recycler adapter use callbacks to retrieve the data from your data model
4. On recycler setup complete hide the progress bar and set the recycler view visible.

This will make your recycler smoothly scrollable and decent loading.